Differential 1-form with vanishing z-component function
Let $\omega $ be a closed 2-form in $\mathbb R^3$. Prove that there is $\eta\in \Omega^1(\mathbb R^3)$ of the form $\eta=\eta_1dx+\eta_2dy$ such that $\omega =d\eta$.
I know that if I write $\omega =f_1dy\wedge dz+f_2dz\wedge dx+f_3dx\wedge dy$, then ${\partial f_1\over \partial x}+{\partial f_2\over \partial y}+{\partial f_3\over \partial z}=0$. I need to find smooth function $\eta_1,\eta_2$  from $\mathbb R^3\to \mathbb R$ such that ${-\partial \eta_2\over \partial z}=f_1$,${\partial \eta_1\over \partial z} =f_2 $, and ${-\partial\eta_1\over \partial y }+{\partial \eta_2\over \partial x}=f_3$. However, I have no idea how to determine them.

You can sum up your PDEs as
$$
\nabla\times\pmatrix{\eta_1\\eta_2\0}=\pmatrix{f_1\f_2\f_3},.
$$
In other words, you are looking for the anti-curl of the divergence free $f,.$
